# Android Database help needed

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-database

I have an activity which has two edit text fields: one for the title and the other for the story.
The entries made two text fields are saved in the database, also the database has a `ROW_ID`,`TITLE_ID` and `STORY_ID`. The entries are displayed in a *list view*.
When an item is long clicked, I get the *row id* corresponding to that item.
How should I get the `TITLE_ID` and `STORY_ID` from this?

Comment: Please post the relevant code and any logcat errors.

Comment: Learning some basic SQL would help your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have the corresponing row id of item which is long clicked in a variable **rid**. Then run the following query:

```
  String q = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where(ROW_ID like '"+rid+"')";
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null); //  db is a object of SQLiteDatabase type
```

Then retrieve **TITLE_ID** and **STORY_ID** like:

```
              if(c.getCount() == 0)
              {                   
                 //No entry found
              }
              else  {
                  c.moveToFirst();
                  do {
                      String titleid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TITLE_ID")); 
                      String storyid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("STORY_ID"));
                      } while (c.moveToNext());                 
            c.close();
```

---

Then use them as you like :)

Comment: There is no reason for a raw query. Using the standard sqlite database interaction of .query() is more than enough. Also its less prone to errors.

Comment: @JoxTraex after lots of googling and going through developer site I was unable to find any perforformance draback of **rawQuery** in comparison with **query()**. Their only difference is with the structure. **query()** needs you to enter different parts of the statement in segments and separate them with commas but statement in **rawQuery** is much easier for a beginner to understand. Should I get a downvote for this?

Comment: Basically the rule is.. if its simpler, its less error prone. Your answer is still right, but your approach to use a raw query for something so simple is overkill.

Comment: @JoxTraex in my humble opinion if there is no performance difference between **rawQuery** and **query** then how can the use of **rawQuery** be a overkill for this simple case?

Comment: its merely the fact that is is more error prone instead of using the simplified classes that were provided by google, if you dont NEED to do a raw query, dont.

Comment: @ Imran Rana :  Thanks man , I used your advice and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the data base for the TITLE_ID and STORY_ID that correspond to the ROW_ID.

Post what code you have and we will be able to give more specific answers.